# How to upload files to Azure DevOps via Power Shell script and Rest API

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I need to upload file to Azure DevOps repository using rest api and power shell scripts. I did this:

```
$token = "token"
$authHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)")) }

$folderPath = "C:/"
$fileName = "TestTXT.txt"
$body = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$folderPath/$fileName")

$org = "orgName"
$project = "projectName"

$createAttachmetUrlTemplate = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$project/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName={fileName}&api-version=5.0"
$postUrl = $createAttachmetUrlTemplate -replace "{filename}", $fileName

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $postUrl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $authHeader -Body $body
```

I have got as result id and url accordingly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/attachments/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1&tabs=HTTP#upload-a-binary-file

[image]

But there isn't any new file in my repo. Where is it? What is wrong? How can I store files in my repo?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this works, but can't you use the `-InFile` parameter? Something like `$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $postUrl -Method Post -InFile 'C:\TestTXT.txt' -ContentType 'multipart/form-data'` (or with a text file use `-ContentType 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API [Attachments - Create - REST API](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Frest%2Fapi%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fwit%2Fattachments%2Fcreate%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-rest-6.1%26tabs%3DHTTP%23upload-a-binary-file&data=05%7C01%7Cv-douxu%40microsoft.com%7Cc9b193468b4d47757d9308dad1119591%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C638052170762312057%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=dunPQO9fVaaHGuDz%2FNKjEm6pSKpmQw6sym%2Buz4JeG24%3D&reserved=0)  you use to upload files works well. And it uploads files to attachment store but not your repo. The url shows the storage address of files .You can download the files through the url.

If you want to store files in your repo, you can use this REST API:[Pushes - Create](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Frest%2Fapi%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fgit%2Fpushes%2Fcreate%3Fview%3Dazure-devops-rest-4.1%26tabs%3DHTTP%23add-a-text-file&data=05%7C01%7Cv-douxu%40microsoft.com%7Cc9b193468b4d47757d9308dad1119591%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C638052170762312057%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=rLp35%2Bau6v8%2FX5mwzgvmxk5DD%2Fe9Yy%2BaTSPvxS3IWaI%3D&reserved=0)

For example: upload a `upload.txt` to my repo

URL

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=4.1
```

Request body

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/main",
      "oldObjectId": "the objectId of ref"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added upload.txt file.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "add",
          "item": {
            "path": "/upload.txt"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "this is conetent of upload.txt",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Test in postman:
[image: RESULT]

You will see the `upload.txt` in your repo.
[image: file in repo]