# Can I send a generated file from Azure Pipeline to a second repository?

Tags: git, powershell, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, sbom

I’m new to the CI thing. I have an Azure Pipeline that generates a file based on my main repository. I want to know the best way to get this generated file and **Commit** it to another repository (without affecting the main repository).

Basically:
`[Pipeline of Main Repository] --> [Generate file] --> [Commit to secondary repository]`

Important: The second repository doesn’t belong to the same organization.

I have not been able to find information on whether it is possible to clone and commit to a repository within a pipeline without affecting the main repository.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is this file and what is the purpose of pushing it to a different repository?

Comment: Versioning BOM file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make it work with the following steps.

Steps:

1. [Create an Azure Repos service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) for the Azure Repo in another organization with your [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#create-a-pat).
   [image]
2. [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://Check%20out%20multiple%20repositories%20in%20your%20pipeline). The source code is checked out into directories named after the repositories as a subfolder  `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. In my sample, the self repo path is `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/selfreponame`, the second repo path is `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/testrepo`.
3. Use git command to push the generated file to the second repo in the bash task.

Sample yaml:

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository # In a different organization
    endpoint: OtherReposServiceConnection
    type: git
    name: testproject/testrepo
    ref: refs/heads/main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository
  persistCredentials: true

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # create a new txt file
      echo "This is a text file." > myFile.txt      
      # copy the file to the folder of that repo. You can copy your generated file here.
      cp myFile.txt $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/testrepo
      
      cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/testrepo
      
      git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
      git config --global user.name "Your Name"
      git fetch
      git checkout main
      git add --all
      git commit -m "Add myFile.txt"
      git push
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried something very similar, I cloned the project using the URL (with PAT) inside `Agents.TempDirectory`.

`git clone $(url) "$(Agent.TempDirectory)/MyRepo"`

And it worked very well.

Answer (score -1):

You may consider using rest api: [Add a binary file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP#add-a-binary-file). In this case, you need:

1. Create PAT on the second team project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows
2. Add a push step to your build: [How to upload files to Azure DevOps via Power Shell script and Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74591525/how-to-upload-files-to-azure-devops-via-power-shell-script-and-rest-api)

Comment: Additional example: [UpdateBinaryGitFile](https://github.com/ashamrai/AzureDevOpsExtensions/blob/master/CustomPSTasks/UpdateBinaryGitFile.ps1)